# ' '.join(context.args) recieves only strings how can i make it recieve int?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

See my code first:

```
def data(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):

    user_says = ' '.join(context.args)
```

so the problem here is that user_says only accepts string even if the user wrote 1 it takes it as '1' how can I make it take 1 or any int as itself?

Comment: Why can you not use an int coerced to a string (such as `str(1)`?

Comment: Why do you want it to take int?

Comment: because I am using an api that receives int objects only not str @nobleknight

Comment: Join function only accepts iterable collections of strings.. Same reason why `'string' + 1` fails

Comment: `user_says = ' '.join(str(x) for x in context.args)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always parse the `int` to `string` and the use `.join` like this

```
user_says = ' '.join(str(context.args))
```

Hope this is the answer you're looking for, if not please specify :)

Comment: This isn't joining anything as `str(context.args)` is a single item

Comment: @OneCricketeer `str` are also iterables containing `str` (single characters), so if the integer needs to be represented by multiple digits, this will insert spaces. So `" ".join(str(1234))` returns `"1 2 3 4"`. Of course, OP didn't make it clear if this is what they want to happen to integers.